# How to run a script which has Java command via Eclipse IDE such that I see the output and interact with the program?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to execute the following command via script through Eclipse.

```
java -cp /home/pallavi/KeplereeWorkspace/trace/target/classes:/home/pallavi/git/thesis-2016/Soot_Instrumentation/sootOutput org.employee.Employee
```

I run it like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./src/main/resources/Intrumentation_Execution.sh");
```

The program "Employee" is an interactive program which means that user needs to select options and different output/processes may occur. If I use BufferedReader I see only the initial printlines and no user input can be given. when I run the Intrumentation_Execution.sh from terminal everything works fine. However, I need to run it through another Java Program.

Also note, I cannot call the main method of Employee in my execution class because I am building an automated tool for which Employee is just a test case per say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bridge to speak to the Java process which is started from the shell script. Something like the below:

**startreader.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "" > inputbridge.txt
tailf inputbridge.txt | java SampleRead
```

**SampleRead.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SampleRead {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int readValue = 0;
        while((readValue = scanner.nextInt()) != 5) {
            System.out.println("Send me something other than " + readValue);
        }
        System.out.println("Good job. Bye");
    }
}
```

**NumberGenerator.java**

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NumberGenerator {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("./startreader.sh");
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        Scanner processStreamReader = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
        String processInputString = null;
        do {
            try(FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("inputbridge.txt", true)) {
                fileWriter.write(((int)(Math.random() * ((10 - 1) + 1)) + 1) + "\n");
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            processInputString = processStreamReader.nextLine();
            System.out.println(processInputString);

        } while(processInputString.startsWith("Send me something other than"));
    }
}
```

**Steps to run:**

1. Compile `SampleRead.java` and `NumberGenerator.java`
2. Provide execute permission for `startreader.sh`
3. Run `java NumberGenerator`

**Output**

```
[jjithin@sjawanpopst8 java]$ java NumberGenerator 
Send me something other than 1
Send me something other than 6
Send me something other than 8
Send me something other than 4
Good job. Bye
[jjithin@sjawanpopst8 java]$ cat inputbridge.txt 

1
6
8
4
5
```

**How this works:**
The bridge between the `NumberGenerator` and `SampleRead` is `inputbridge.txt` file generated through `startreader.sh`. When `NumberGenerator` is run, it executes `startreader.sh` which generates `inputbridge.txt` and empties it. The next stage in `startreader.sh` is to do `tailf` on `inputbridge.txt` file. Any new line written to this file will become the input to `SampleRead` via `tailf` process.

When `NumberGenerator` randomly picks a number and sends to `SampleRead` by writing to `inputbridge.txt`, it gets received by `SampleRead`, checks if it is of value 5. Other than value 5 will output "Send me something..." which is read by `NumberGenerator` through the `ProcessInputStream`.

This approach should be enhanced with check for java process existence after executing the shell script. Moreover, the `tailf` process won't exit until it is killed manually. Hence, `tailf` could be replaced with another proxy java application, which has a communication protocol with `NumberGenerator` kind of application to know when to end execution. You may consider using `Sockets` instead of files if developing a java proxy application.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late response. But I donot get the same output that you indicated her. My output is just a blank screen, on which if I enter any number it does not display anything. Please let me know where I am going wrong